# how to add emblem to windows file icon?

Tags: windows, icons, emblems

I want to know how to add some sort of emblem or badge to a specific file. Just like drop box does to a specific file when it is doing a sync.

I found that the guys from drop box are able to do that on linux by using libnautilus package. But I need to do so on windows and haven't been able to find an answer.

Will the solution change from one windows version to other?

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overlay Icons? you can use `IShellIconOverlayIdentifier`, example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/overlayicon.aspx), supported versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761265%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Overlay Icons was exactly what I was referring to.

Thanks a lot Alex
Regards